# Play sample rest application Issue

Tags: playframework, resteasy

I am created a test application and created hello rest easy class. Then I tried to run using `play run test` and got this exception:

```
21:46:18,246 INFO  ~ RESTEasy plugin: Found resource class: resources.HelloResource
21:46:18,482 WARN  ~ NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load builtin provider: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJacksonProvider
21:46:18,564 INFO  ~ RESTEasy plugin: RESTEasy started
21:46:18,570 INFO  ~ Application 'test' is now started !
21:46:30,083 ERROR ~

@66i4nnpj8
rest.hello action not found

Action not found
Action rest.hello could not be found. Error raised is Controller controllers.rest not found

play.exceptions.ActionNotFoundException: Action rest.hello not found
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.getActionMethod(ActionInvoker.java:436)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:76)
        at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Controller controllers.rest not found
        ... 3 more
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Hi, can you attach the source of the class that you created? And the path where you stored the class?

Answer (score 1):

If you defined resteasy routes at the end of routes file (after `/{controller}/{action}` route), then you get this issue.
Try to move resteasy route declaration at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have a whole application fully working with RESTEasy module of Play. It should help you setup yours: https://github.com/feliperazeek/play-github-api-demo

Answer (score 0):

Fairly old question, but I came across this too when trying to write my first REST service using play, so will post what my problem was here in case others come by this.

Effectively I didn't realise I needed to run play eclipsify on a new project. Steps to generating your first REST service in a new project actually are:

- Make sure you've referenced the correct play jar...
- Add your REST path to the routes file. Something like this:

  ```
  GET   /gimmeStuff     Application.gimmeStuff
  ```
- Add the method to the applicable controller (in my case it's Application). If it's all correct your class will look something like this:

  ```
  public class Application extends Controller {
      public static void gimmeStuff() {
          renderText("STUFF!");
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally... if you haven't done so already run play eclipsify against your project:

  ```
  play eclipsify MyFirstRestProject
  ```

Once I did all the above my problem went away.